# Why did Sally reject the phone call from Gomez Addams?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-addams-family

In The Addams Family (1991), Gomez Addams calls Sally who is on the TV Show,

[image]

But she rejected his call with the words:

> Mr. Addams, please stop calling. We do not know where they meet.

[image]

Why did she reject the phone call from him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TV was showing a daytime programme where someone was being interviewed with the question:

> So your son was brainwashed by voodoo slave masters and forced to recruit      others. Let's take a call.

The **joke** is that Addams was supposed be be interested in that spooky type of activity and was constantly calling for more information even though, in the real world, no-one would believe such an outrageous claim.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OhNoNotAgain